# Is it possible to deploy with Azure scaled out?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have a question about Azure app service plan and Web apps.
I searched the official documentation but couldn't find it.

1. Is it possible to deploy code in a scale-out state (state with multiple instances) with azure?
2. If possible, can you see for each instance whether the deployment was successful?
3. Is log batting possible when scaled out?

If you have a reference site, please let me know.

Comment: scale is basically the copy of the deployment. It will be successful everywhere or not deployment even once. so it won't be deployed in all instances all at once.

Comment: If you have multiple instances, does that mean they will be deployed one at a time? Or if you deploy in scale-out state, does that mean copying the successful instance again to create an instance to scale out? May I ask you for more details?

Comment: the updates go with the update domain logic . be it deployments or os updates..  a slightly older article https://azure.github.io/AppService/2018/01/18/Demystifying-the-magic-behind-App-Service-OS-updates.html  the fact is they will ensure high availability and ensure failed deployments don't bring down the whole set.